# How many 6 digit numbers can be formed with digits 0,1,6,8 which are smaller than 101680

Tags: combinatorics

I don't truly understand how to solve this problem. First step I made was that I found out numbers which don't start with '1' . So we got 2*4*4*4*4*4 = 2048 solutions ,but now,when numbers start with '1' , I don't know how to put things together,or is there any easier solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first digit has 1 choice (1), the second 1 choice (0), the third can be (0,1); if (0), the remaining three do not matter($4^3$ possibilities). If (1), then the fourth digit has 3 choices(0,1,6); For (0,1) there are $2\cdot 4^2$ choices. For (6) there are $3\cdot 4$ choices left. $4^3+2\cdot 4^2+3\cdot 4=108$(6-digit numbers)
[image]